# Liferay - populate list from an external REST service

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

As a newbie to Liferay I want to populate an options list from an external REST service.

First I go to Forms, then Data providers. I add a data provider with a name, description, URL = https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all, no username / password, input 'name' / 'name' / text and output 'name' / 'name' / text. I save that info. As an alternative I tried to restrict the list to this url: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name. Without any improvement.

Then I create a form with an options list that is filled with using the data provider.

After creating a page, adding the form to the page, configuring it and finally publishing the page, the lists shows no country-names.

When looking at the Chrome developer options Network tab, the URL for the restcountries.eu is not called.

In the Configuration Panel / System settings / Data providers I both used the Access Local Network on or off. No difference.

Can you help me filling the list with the country names?

I just downloaded the Liferay CE version, so that will be newest version (July 29. 2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay Forms Data providers are handled on server side, so it is normal to not see any request inside the network-debugger. I guess this is due to security/authentication issues that should not get exposed.

There is a good help article about [Data Providers](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017894712-Data-Providers), that also has some notes about troubleshooting and debugging. If the service is not called, it might not be properly connect to you form control field.